# How do you detect a hidden TARDIS?

Tags: doctor-who

A TARDIS has a form of active camouflage called a chameleon circuit that allows it to take any form.

Has it been shown in the series or extended media that someone can scan or test an object to determine if it's a TARDIS?

I believe the Doctor may have done this to find the Master's TARDIS at some point.

Comment: If I recall correctly, Captain Harkness tracked down the Doctor's TARDIS by "scanning for alien tech" (prompting Rose to gleefully reply, "Finally, a little Spock!"). Or was that his sonic screwdriver?

Comment: Upon further thought, I think I was wrong -- Jack apparently homed in on the Doctor's sonic screwdriver, as evidenced by the fact that he and Rose subsequently meet up with the Doctor in the hospital, not at the TARDIS. Which doesn't say that he *didn't* find the TARDIS, of course, but neither does it say that he did (which would answer your question).

Answer (score 1):

I think the way that the cameleon circuit works, is that it makes the item *non-descript* and unimportant looking, hiding it from people who don't know what they're looking for. Compare to the [SEP field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somebody_Else%27s_Problem#In_fiction) in H2G2. If you know what to look for, you can find it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll admit up front that I haven't seen all of Doctor Who.  However, the idea behind the chameleon circuit is to make the TARDIS undetectable.  So it shouldn't be possible to detect a properly chameleoned TARDIS.  I recall from an old Doctor Who episode I once watched that there was a hidden TARDIS that belonged to one of the Doctor's foes, and at no point did the Doctor break out a device to detect said TARDIS.  The foe had to reveal it for the Doctor to find it.  (Given [The Master's TARDIS'](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Master%27s_TARDIS) large list of disguises, I suspect it was a story where the Master used his TARDIS' chameleon circuit to keep it hidden)

Comment: Of course, he may not have looked for one because he didn't expect to find one? Would you scan for something you didn't think existed?